On Amplify Push getting "Packaging lambda function failed"
I tried amplify push and got the error:

Packaging lambda function failed with the error
Command failed with exit code 1: yarn workspaces focus --production
Unknown Syntax Error: Command not found; did you mean:
$ yarn workspaces list [--since] [-R,--recursive] [--no-private] [-v,--verbose] [--json]
While running workspaces focus --production
ERROR ON amplify push

I tried to push using amplify push but I am getting the mentioned error somehow related to yarn. The lambda package fails.
